# Connexion to a remote PostgreSQL database works in command line but not through GUI

Tags: c#, postgresql, command-line, database-connection, remote-access

I need to connect to a remote postgreSQL database own by another person

**Through a GUI I get the error** in the following screenshot

[image: GUI error]

I told them to check if they allows remote access to their database and indeed they do.

What i don't understand is that **I can access the database through command line** without error

```
C:\Users\François CHIV>psql -h xxx -U xxx -d d70xxx
Mot de passe pour l'utilisateur xxx :
psql (14.5, serveur 13.8 (Ubuntu 13.8-1.pgdg20.04+1))
Attention : l'encodage console (850) diffère de l'encodage Windows 
(1252).
    Les caractères 8 bits peuvent ne pas fonctionner correctement.
    Voir la section « Notes aux utilisateurs de Windows » de la 
    page référence de psql pour les détails.
Connexion SSL (protocole : TLSv1.3, chiffrement : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits : 256, compression : désactivé)
Saisissez « help » pour l'aide.

d7xxx=>
```

Is there some steps I'm missing ? I have never connecting to a remote database that is why i need your expertise

The driver used is this one https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/

Comment: The SO concept suggests not to post Images only but (formatted) text. When there is a Error MessageBox involved, you can normally press `Ctrl+C` to copy its content

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're welcome!, the reason is that a web search works better with text than images for the time being

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is clear: There is no entry in `pg_hba.conf` for user  when connecting to database  from host  with SSL disabled.

That could be because  is different from , or because your GUI does not attempt an SSL connection, and the server requires it.

That's as good an answer as you can expect without showing `pg_hba.conf` or any other details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I don't have access to the pg_hba.conf file and no other details than the confidential connection information provided by the person.
I'll check for SSL

Comment: It was indeed the SSLMode=Allow options that had to be set